# My car almost always gets into a drift while making turns

Tags: grid-2

I recently started playing GRID 2, and from what I have seen, my car almost always gets into a drift while making turns even during normal grip races, note that I am playing with a keyboard. So, I wanted to ask whether the problem is because I am playing with a Keyboard, or the handling model itself is like that?
Thanks!

Comment: Never played the Grid games, but I'm willing to bet that the drift mechanic exists for the game, and not just because you're using a keyboard. The reason it may seem excessive is likely due to a key press being all or nothing, on or off, full turn or straight on. There's no nuance for direction that you might get with a controller or steering wheel.

Comment: Is it full on ***drift*** (ie reverse lock etc) or just a bit of slippage/oversteer ?

Comment: That is why this game could be hard to begin, every car drifts **a lot** and when you don't have suffisant knowledge of circuit layout, you could go into a wall really easily (I play with a Xbox controller and I've got some drift too)